# Unable to create dataframe with pandas DateRange and multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a df as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 'S0001', 1: 'S0002', 2: 'S0003'},
 'StartDate': {0: Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00')},
 'EndDate': {0: Timestamp('2019-01-02 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-04-01 00:00:00')}
 'Color': {0: 'Blue', 1: 'Green', 2: 'Red'},
 'Type': {0: 'Small', 1: 'Mid', 2: 'Mid'}})
```

Now I want to create a df with 366 rows between Start and End dates and I want to add the Color, Type, ID for every row between Start and End Date.

I'm doing the following whick works well:

```
OutputDF = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data = Row['ID'], index = pd.date_range(Row['StartDate'], Row['EndDate'], freq='1D', closed = 'left'), columns = ['ID']) for index, Row in df.iterrows()])
```

and I get a df with 2 columns SiteID and days in the range Start/End Dates.

I'm able to add the Color/Type by doing a pd.merge on 'ID' but I think there is a direct way to add the column Color and Type directly when creating the DF.

I've tried `data = [Row['ID'], Row['Type'], Row['Color']]` or `data = Row[['ID', 'Color', 'Type']]` but neither works.

Therefore, how should I do to create my dataframe but having the Color for every item for the whole 366 rows directly without requiring the merge ?

Sample of current output:
[image]

It goes on for all the days between Start/End dates for each item.

Desired output:

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, pd.DataFrame constructor with a dictionary for data:

```
 pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'ID':Row['ID'], 
                          'Color':Row['Color'], 
                          'Type':Row['Type']}, 
                         index = pd.date_range(Row['StartDate'], 
                                               Row['EndDate'], 
                                               freq='1D', 
                                               closed = 'left')) 
            for index, Row in df.iterrows()])
```